# Should I use C-Linq or a Partial View - or both - to filter on two different view IDs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t-sql, stored-procedures, razor-pages

I have a very limited knowledge of .net mvs razor pages. so hopefully my question makes sense.

1. I have a movie database, with a:

   a. media table (dvd, vhs, etc)

   b. genres table

   c. movies table
2. I'd like to be able to click on media type - ie DVD - and have it generate a list of genres that I have available on DVD. I've created a stored procedure for this and a razor page that does this succesfully.
3. I also have a stored procedure that displays movies of a certain genre. And a razor page that generates all movies within a genre.

The problem I am trying to resolve is linking these two. How do I get to this flow: click on dvd => list all of my DVD genres => click on "Thriller" genre and display all DVDs that are Thrillers.

In my "Media" razor page, I list the media types and display the genres model, which generates genres when I execute my "MediaByGenre" list. The code is below:

```
@page
@model MyMovies.Pages.GenreDetails.DetailsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h4>Genres</h4>
<hr />
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Genre</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Genres)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="col-sm-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.GenreName)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

In my "Genre" razor page, I display my movie model that executes the procedure to generate "GetMovieByGenre". Here is the razor code below:

```
@page
@model MyMovies.Pages.MovieDetails.DetailsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<table col-width=500>

    <tr>
        <th class="col-sm-2">Movie Title</th>
        <th class="col-sm-2">Movie Year</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Movies)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.MovieTitle)
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.MovieYear)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<div>
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

I have tried using an a-tag here:

```
<td class="col-sm-10">
      @Html.DisplayFor(Model => item.GenreName)
</td>
```

to link to the movie model generated for each genre, but that doesn't work because I can only use one model (the genre model). Does this call for using a partial view? Or can I solve this in my .cshtml.cs file using some C-Linq? I don't want to expend too much energy taking the wrong route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple models in `tuple` format in a single page, but I'm afraid that dose not help you here. 
Use partial view and append partial response to your page.
Stored Procedure or LINQ, use whatever you like, but i prefer ORM in this case so you can go with LINQ with partial view.

To know how to use multiple model in single page, This article may help you

[multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/)

Take a look at that, maybe this won't solve your problem but you may learn something.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for model-view-viewmodel? This version uses controllers, which I am not using.